# nova client image create

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Does anyone know where nova put the temporary image of the running instance while it is creating the snapshot? for some reason my snapshot image in glance stays in SAVING mode.

Answer (score 0):

What version of nova are you running? What hypervisor?

Assuming essex with libvirt (the default in most packages), then they're saved to /tmp, which can be overridden with the TMPDIR environment variable.

If you're using folsom, but still with libvirt, then the value of the libvirt_snapshot_directory flag is used. The default value is a subdirectory of your instances path named "snapshots".

These snapshots can be quite large, which is why where you put them on disk matters.